# spring data jdbc and sequence

Tags: mariadb, spring-data

I use spring data jdbc and mariadb.

With spring data jpa for a sequence we can do

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="xxxx_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="xxxx_id_seq",sequenceName="xxxx_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
Long id;
```

What is the solution for spring data jdbc?